# Starting a node server and leaving it running

Tags: node.js, ssh

This may be a stupid question, sorry.
But I SSH into a server and run my node server with the command:
node server.js

I note however that if my SSH sessions stops abruptly (internet cuts out etc) then I am confronted with an error. Network error unexpectedly closed session or something similar.

I then note that my node server has actually stopped. However nothing has actually gone wrong. It was as if I had Ctrl + C'd but otherwise I simply timed out from my SSH session.

So clearly I'm doing something wrong. Is there a way to ssh in, run the serve rand disconnect without the server turning itself off or similar? Or to avoid my SSH session collapsing and taking the server with it?

Comment: The session that you were running the `node` process from disconnected so it stopped all session processes, including your node application?

Comment: You can use `nohup` http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/man1/nohup.1.html, if you are on Ubuntu / Linux!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are not on Windows, you can just start it without a console like this:

```
node server.js &
```

And, then it won't be wired into your ssh console.

Or, you can use something like `forever` to launch node as its own process and then monitor it and auto-restart it.

```
forever server.js
```

Lots more info [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89483/keeping-a-process-running-after-putty-or-terminal-has-been-closed).

Comment: Perfect :) Thanks - and the nohup in the link means I can close the terminal also (I am on windows - but the server is a linux one)